# Bootstrap JS - collapsible with toggle

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, collapsable

Alright, so I've got this js code:

```
jQuery(".toggle-panel").click(function() {
  jQuery('#collapsible-element').collapse({
    toggle: true,
  });
});
```

I assume it should open and close #collapsible-element but it can only close it. This #collapsible-element has also classes "collapse in" attached by myself in code. With first click on .toggle-panel  it closes the #collapsible-element, but the second click does not open it again. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any additional JavaScript code for toggle if you are using bootstrap. check out the following:

http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse

Comment: what do you mean I don't need? I've seen this documentation already. There must be a click event, otherwise page woudn't know what collapse is triggered by.

Comment: @David If you read the example carefully you will see data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" properties. So these properties are handled in bootstrap. Just copy paste the sample code in the link and it will work, provided full bootstrap.js is included